# Sistema de notificacões

Tags: python-3.x, django

Tenho o seguinte modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('nombre',max_length = 255)
    place = models.CharField('lugar',max_length = 255)
    thematic = models.CharField('tema',max_length = 100)
    title_of_the_paper = models.CharField('tema abordado',max_length = 60)
    date_event  = models.DateField('realizado el', auto_now_add=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'professor.Professor', related_name='eventos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'evento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'eventos'
        db_table = 'event'
```

Quero implementar um sistema de notificacões, que quando un usuario inserta um evento que me notifique a todos otros usuarios sobre o evento creado.
Que packet devo utilizar o como posso modificar a vista?

Esta é a vista

```
def ajax_create_event(request):
    event_form = EventForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        place = request.POST['place']
        thematic = request.POST['thematic']
        title_of_the_paper = request.POST['title_of_the_paper']
        date_event = request.POST['date_event']
        author = request.user.teacher_profile
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            Event.objects.create(
                name=name, place=place, thematic=thematic,title_of_the_paper = title_of_the_paper,date_event = date_event, author=author
            )
            events = Event.objects.filter(author=author)
            data = {
                'msg': 'El evento se ha guardado satisfactoriamente',
                'page': render_to_string('event/list.html', {'events': events}, request=request),
                'header': render_to_string('event/dinamic_event.html', request=request),
                'event': request.user.teacher_profile.number_of_events
            }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data = {
            'page': render_to_string('event/add.html', {'form': event_form}, request=request)
        }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Não bastaria mandar um e-mail para os usuários após fazer o `Event.objects.create`?

Answer (score 0):

O `Django` já permite que você faça isso implementando `Signals` que nada mais é do que uma implementação do `design pattern` `Observer` que permite que você em determinados momentos como antes de salvar, ao salvar ou deletar um objeto avise outro que esteja interessado nesse determinado evento,  sugiro que você dê uma olhada em [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/) que resolverá o seu problema.